# install thingsboard but there is not “Devices” section

Tags: thingsboard

I  install thingsboard  on windows10 I used this site"https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows/"to install.
I want do this project "https://www.hackster.io/thingsboard/temperature-dashboard-using-arduino-uno-esp8266-and-mqtt-5e26eb"

after install complete when login http://localhost:8080 with
 login: sysadmin@thingsboard.org password: sysadmin i want add devise but there is not “Devices” section.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please keep in mind we have no context and edit your question to fully explain all the details, including what you want to accomplish, what you've tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problems. It appears the getting started tutorial misses a few steps.

First try creating a new Tenant, then create a new user. You should then see the missing sections appear!
In order to have a device you must have a tenant to link it to. I'm learning as you are.

(If you attempt the OPC Connection) When you have gotten past this point yet you will also see that there are certificate errors if you will try to connect to the *KepServerEX* demo as mentioned in the getting started tutorial. I changed the time on my computer, since the certificate is expired as of this month, a date that has already passed (I don't recall exactly when).

Once you get past that small hurdle you will find another problem with the demo configuration, as explained here: https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard-gateway/issues/30

Answer (score 2):

All dashboards and customers in Thingsboard are tied to a Tenant. Thingsboard support multiple Tenants. When you are logged in as system administrator, Thingsboard can't know which of the tenants to show, so no dashboards or customers are shown.

The system administrator account is for system administration tasks, not for dashboard or customer tasks. If you want to manage dashboards or customers, login as the Tenant or Customer you want to manage.

Comment: This is so weird!

Answer (score 0):

You should try with different user:

> username: tenant@thingsboard.org
>
> password: tenant

pretty much mentioned in the doc!!!
[image: here]